# Android Logcat strange errors

Tags: android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-gradle-plugin, genymotion, android-logcat

I am new to Android app developing. While running my app on Genymotion (I have tried with multiple devices), the gradle builds without error, but the emulator says "Unfortunately, Fictiopedia has stopped.", and the Logcat shows lots of errors I can't understand. It's an app that creates its own words by randomly displaying meaningful parts of actual English words and their definition accordingly. (I deleted a large part of the code with words and their definition to make it fit in this question box)

Thanks for helping.

Here, what the Logcat displays and my code:

LOGCAT:

```
12-27 11:09:05.099 1946-1946/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system
12-27 11:09:05.099 1946-1946/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
12-27 11:09:05.099 1946-1946/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-27 11:09:05.143 1946-1956/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
12-27 11:09:05.360 1946-1946/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
12-27 11:09:05.454 1946-1946/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-27 11:09:05.690 1946-1946/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060054 (t=5 e=84) (error -75)
12-27 11:09:05.691 1946-1946/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060054 (t=5 e=84) (error -75)
12-27 11:09:05.692 1946-1946/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                 --------- beginning of crash
12-27 11:09:05.693 1946-1946/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.lauramessner.fictiopedia, PID: 1946
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lauramessner.fictiopedia/com.example.lauramessner.fictiopedia.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                     at com.example.lauramessner.fictiopedia.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060054
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                     at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                     at com.example.lauramessner.fictiopedia.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
12-27 11:09:10.334 1946-1946/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1946 SIG: 9
```

MY CODE:

```
package com.example.lauramessner.fictiopedia;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public void happen(View b){
```

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final TextView pref = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pref);
        final TextView root = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.root);
        final TextView suff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.suff);
        final TextView predef = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.predef);
        final TextView rootdef = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rootdef);
        final TextView suffdef = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.suffdef);

        final String[] prefixes =  {"", "A", "An", "Ab", "Ad", "Ambi", "Ana", "Ante", "Anti", "Apo", "Auto","Bene"};
        final String[] roots = {"", "ami", "ann", "anthrop", "aqua"};
         final String[] suffixes = {"", "agog", "agogue", "cide", "ectomy"};


        ImageButton pushMe = findViewById(R.id.pushMe);
        pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 final int rando = (int) (Math.random());
                 suff.setText(prefixes[rando]);
                 root.setText(roots[rando]);
                 pref.setText(suffixes[rando]);



                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("")) {
                    predef.setText("");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("A")) {
                    predef.setText("not ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("An")) {
                    predef.setText("without ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("Ab")) {
                    predef.setText("away from ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("Ad")) {
                    predef.setText("toward ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("Ambi")) {
                    predef.setText("both ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("Ana")) {
                    predef.setText("again ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("Ante")) {
                    predef.setText("before ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("Anti")) {
                    predef.setText("against ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("Apo")) {
                    predef.setText("away from ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("Auto")) {
                    predef.setText("self ");
                }
                if (pref.getText().toString().contains("Bene")) {
                    predef.setText("good ");
                }

                if (root.getText().toString().contains("")) {
                    rootdef.setText("");
                }
                if (root.getText().toString().contains("ami")) {
                    rootdef.setText("love");
                }
                if (root.getText().toString().contains("ann")) {
                    rootdef.setText("year");
                }
                if (root.getText().toString().contains("anthrop")) {
                    rootdef.setText("human");
                }
                if (root.getText().toString().contains("aqua")) {
                    rootdef.setText("water");
                }

                if (suff.getText().toString().contains("")) {
                    suffdef.setText("");
                }
                if (suff.getText().toString().contains("agog")) {
                    suffdef.setText("Leader ");
                }
                if (suff.getText().toString().contains("agogue")) {
                    suffdef.setText("Leader ");
                }
                if (suff.getText().toString().contains("cide")) {
                    suffdef.setText("Act of killing ");
                }
                if (suff.getText().toString().contains("ectomy")) {
                    suffdef.setText("Surgical removal of ");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems a problem in your MainActivity layout. A resource that can not be found (Resource ID #0x7f060054) on an ImageView

Comment: The problem is somewhere in your R.layout.activity_main

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) I finally corrected it.

Comment: It's OK. Glad to help. I suppose you could delete your question if it's nothing of interest to others on the ressolution of this problem.